# Uppercase letters in a string. Python 2.7

Tags: python

I have researched the string.upper() command and can't seem to figure out how to print a string where only the first letter is upper cased.

```
string = 'name'
print string.upper()

print string[0].upper(), string[1:]
```

Could someone please give me a hint on how to do this?

Comment: `string.capitalize()`

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to capitalize just the m in 'name'? print string.capitalize(2)? I'm a little confused on what goes in the ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.capitalize` does exactly what you need.

```
capitalize(...)
    S.capitalize() -> string

    Return a copy of the string S with only its first character
    capitalized.
```

Related is

```
title(...)
    S.title() -> string

    Return a titlecased version of S, i.e. words start with uppercase
    characters, all remaining cased characters have lowercase.
```

Note that `capitalize` makes all the following letters lowercase. ie equivalent to
`string[0].upper() + string[1:].lower()`.
 So if you need to preserve the case of those, you'll need to stick to your original solution

```
>>> "fOO".capitalize()
'Foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a string method [capitalize](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) for this purpose.

```
>>> string = "hello world"
>>> string.capitalize()
'Hello world'
```

Comment: Duplicate of the accepted answer.... And also not as elaborated as @JohnLaRooy's answer.